# Read out Thunderbird unread mail? (linux, terminal)

Tags: c, email, ubuntu, thunderbird, dwm

I am about building a statusbar for dwm,
i want to read out the unread-mail-count via terminal (with grep, sed, or fopen as a file)
and get it via fopen/popen.

I am using ubuntu/dwm/thunderbird 16.
I Think there is no text-file containing the unread-email count...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> go to ~/.thunderbird/default/

search in

> Imapmail/../INBOX

or in

> Mail/../INBOX

for files without any extension.They contain your mails.Do the following

> cat `<file>`|grep -c X:Mozilla-Status: 0000

This will give you an unread mail count,since your unread mail have X:Mozilla-Status as 0000

For other statuses go through the different X:Mozilla-Statuses

Comment: I have looked at the contents of my INBOX file and located the entry for an unread email and it, like all the other entries in the file, has `X:Mozilla-Status: 0001`.

Answer (score 1):

[NOT AN ANSWER]

I dont have enough rep to comment on the bellow answer (Anurag's answer). But grepping/counting for X:Mozilla-Status: 0000 isn't working anymore. I tried that for a conky script. even for unread the status is 0001. i have tested with ubuntu 12.10 and thunderbird 16. Here's the same question asked on [getsatisfaction.com (external link)](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/x_mozilla_status_flags_are_not_being_used_all_messages_marked_read).

You can also count "X:Mozilla-Status:" and "X:Mozilla-Status: 0001", both will return the same no matter what is the state of you inbox. It seems X:Mozilla-Status is not being used at all. [(Ref.)](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsMsgMessageFlags.idl)

*** I ran my searches for IMAP inbox. maybe that's the reason. maybe IMAP's info is stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

cat | grep'ing (as explained by other answers) for "X-Mozilla-Status: 0001" currently works for me. Thunderbird version 91.9.1-1.

Comment: Please give a complete command and use code formatting. Also you should consider separating your commands and instruction to provide more clarity and improved readability. Btw, nice answer!